# Как скопировать все кнопки WinForms в двумерный массив?

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

Существует у меня квадрат из кнопок, размером 5х5 в WinForms. 
Есть у меня и двумерный массив, куда и нужно поместить все 25 кнопок(с учётом местонахождения, конечно), для дальнейшего перебора и изменения параметров.
Вопрос: Как наиболее эффективно поместить кнопки за названиями `btn1, btn2...` в двумерный массив. Я, конечно, могу их ручками поместить в массив, но 25 строк писать для этого не кажется хорошим решением. Что можно сделать или изменить(что-то в массиве, например), для хорошего решения?

Comment: Научитесь писать циклы. Дополнительно может пригодится нахождение кнопки по имени или перебор коллекции кнопок. Например, что-то типа [тынц1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4483912/5752652) и [тынц2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2bf0d768-6859-4489-b488-154d7c6a95be/how-to-get-button-collection-on-a-winform?forum=csharplanguage)

Comment: Ну хорошо. Предположим, я буду использовать два цикла for. Если по двумерному массиву я представляю как пройтись, что мне делать с кнопками? Как их поместить автоматически в массив?

P.S: Увидел правку, сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: А этого вы не объяснили сами. У вас судя по тексту вопроса ОДИН ряд кнопок (слово "один" пропущено, но легко восстанавливается). Как записать ОДИН ряд в двумерный массив -- вам решать. Ладно бы вы сказали, что у вас кнопок в несколько рядов и нужно их также в двумерный массив записать, как-то преобразуя координаты. Но похоже что вы и сами не особо понимаете чего хотите добиться. Может быть хотели ОДИН ряд кнопок в одномерный массив записать, не?

Comment: Нет, как раз рядов несколько. У меня квадрат 5х5 из кнопок(25 кнопок). То есть 5 рядов кнопок.
Сейчас исправлю, "Ряд" у меня здесь в смысле "несколько".

Comment: Тогда вам нужно в цикле получать координаты X, Y каждой кнопки и на их основании вычислять индекс в двумерном массиве. Разумеется, это возможно, если у вас кнопки расставлены строго по сетке: известна ширина и высота кнопки и расстояние между элементами по горизонтали и вертикали. Рисуйте клеточки, думайте над формулой. Возможно, для начала проще будет решить [обратную задачу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23753946/5752652): из имеющегося массива создать кнопки на форме, а потом до вас дойдёт как решить исходную задачу.

Comment: Да, они стоят по порядку. Сейчас ещё сумел найти на примере ваших ссылок вариант решения с `this.Controls("btn" + i.ToString())`, попробую помутить с названиями кнопок и написать так.
Если не получится - попробую воспользоваться вашим вариантом.

Comment: Был ли мой ответ полезен?

Comment: @aepot
Извините, не увидел, так как на тот момент смог решить задачу через `Controls.Find()`, пока времени нету что написать свой вариант здесь.
Ваш, в вероятно, более правильный подход, ибо я сделал через имена (это было учебное задание, поэтому такая логика подошла). Хотя его попробовать смогу только позже.
В любом случае, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда интерфейс хранит данные - это как хвост виляет собакой.

Если вам нужно хранить данные о кнопках, значит сами кнопки изначально должны появиться на форме на основе этих данных. То есть не нужно брать кнопки и засовывать в массив. Нужно брать массив и изначально на его основе создавать кнопки. Тогда вопрос отпадет сам собой.

К примеру, создадим класс данных.

```cs
public class ButtonInfo
{
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Заполним к примеру его тестовыми данными и нарисуем на форме кнопки, пусть нам нужно нарисовать клавиатуру для калькулятора.

Я создал новый проект и написал такой код

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // создаем массив
        ButtonInfo[] buttons = new ButtonInfo[12];

        // заполняем массив
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i] = new ButtonInfo 
            { 
                Location = new Point(i % 3 * 100 + 10, i / 3 * 100 + 10),
                Text = i switch 
                { 
                    < 9 => (i + 1).ToString(),
                    9 => "±",
                    10 => "0",
                    11 => ",",
                    _ => "Кнопка"
                } 
            };
        }

        // выводим кнопки на форму
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button 
            { 
                Text = buttons[i].Text, 
                Location = buttons[i].Location, 
                Size = new Size(90, 90),
                Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 24, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)
            };
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
    }

    // при нажатии на любую кнопку сработает этот обработчик события
    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        MessageBox.Show($"Нажата кнопка '{btn.Text}'");
    }
}
```

На форме выглядит это так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку выскакивает сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение вашего вопроса заключается в хранении и передаче массива `ButtonInfo[]`. А на основе этого массива вы сможете сгенерить этот же интерфейс в любой форме. И не потребуются никакие имена для кнопок. Если название `Text` кнопки не подходит для идентификации самой кнопки или у вас несколько кнопок с одинм и тем же текстом, используйте например `Button.Tag`, записывая туда то что нужно, и считывайте значение в обработчике события.

А контролы должны жить на форме, их не нужно никуда переносить и нигде хранить. К тому же когда форма закроется, она задиспозит все созданные вами кнопки и вы больше не сможете их нигде использовать.