# c# Заполнение ComboBox в цикле

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

Есть у меня 10 comboBox.

[image: https://pastenow.ru/CVYP2]

Мне нужно их заполнить элементами из dataGridView, которая выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-нибудь заполнить эти comboBox через цикл? Как-нибудь вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что у меня всегда разное количество Ингредиентов, при выборе разного товара, поэтому нельзя просто написать через присвоение для каждого, т.к. будут ошибки.

Конечно, можно сделать вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это выглядит крайне тупо и некрасиво

Comment: можно пустой catch на каждое присвоение в цикле поставить, что сможет присвоиться, то присвоится: for { try { combo=cell } catch {} }

Comment: Не особо понял....

Comment: расшифровываю псевдокод 'combo=cell': comboBox[i].Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString(). я не претендую на решение, но обратил внимание, что в первом случае нет обработки исключений (и ожидание ошибок), а во втором случае есть обработчик.

Comment: Контролы на форму добавлять можно не только в дизайнере. Следовательно и изменять их можно програмно не только по именам. Да и вообще контролам, которых много, смысла давать имена мало. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1296394/373567 `foreach (ComboBox cbox in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()) { ... }` или `ComboBox[] boxes = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToArray()`, ну а как с массивом работать в цикле вы же знаете?

Comment: И код вставлять надо текстом.

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное. Единственная странность - он почему-то добавляет в таком порядке: 6,7,8,9,10,5,4,3,2,1 (число - номер combobox) https://pastenow.ru/CW0B1

Comment: В каком порядке комбобоксы были добавлены на форму, в таком и добавляет.

Comment: `this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().OrderBy(c => int.Parse(c.Name.SubString(8)))`, но это само по себе костыль.

Comment: Спасибо. Всё идеально стало работать

Comment: Вы можете опубликовать решение в ответе, если считаете, что оно может быть полезно будущим посетителям и позднее принять ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, вот такое конечное решение получилось:

```
            int temp = 1; //добавление ингредиентов в комбобоксы
            try
            {
                ComboBox[] boxes = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
                {
                    boxes[i].Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[temp].Value.ToString().Split(',')[0];
                    temp++;
                }
            }
            catch { }
```