# Как редактировать сразу несколько Label'ов в C# WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label

Пишу игру 2048. Решил сделать клетки используя Label. Не хочется постоянно для каждого отдельного label прописывать один и тот же параметр. Можно ли как-нибудь объединить их в одну группу и редактировать сразу все, либо же есть какая-то фишка для быстрого редактирования?

А то приходится делать вот так:

```
label1.Text = ""; label2.Text = ""; label3.Text = ""; label4.Text = "";
label5.Text = ""; label6.Text = ""; label7.Text = ""; label8.Text = "";
label9.Text = ""; label10.Text = ""; label11.Text = ""; label12.Text = "";
label13.Text = ""; label14.Text = ""; label15.Text = ""; label16.Text = "";
```

Comment: [Загляните сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1296394/373567), методика в принципе та же, что вам нужна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто поместить все лейблы на какой-то контрол, например панель `panel1`. Тогда все лейблы можно будет перебрать так:

```
foreach (var label in panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    label.Text = "";
```

Comment: Подправил код, если вы не против.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, писал код по памяти, поэтому немножко перепутал название функции `OfType`))

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.

Можно поместить Label в один массив:

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>() { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6,
label7, label8, label9, label10, label11, label12, label13, label14, label15, label16 };
```

Перебирать их через цикл for:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 15;  i++)
{
    labels[i].Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Не стоит хранить контролы в своих коллекциях, контролы должны жить в форме и только там, воспользуйтесь лучше соседним ответом. Генерируйте интерфейс програмно, не руками в дизайнере. Подсказка в ссылке в комментарии под вопросом.