# Прелоадер для windows form C#

Tags: c#, form, таймер, splash-screen

Имеется приложение, общающиеся с микроконтроллером висящем на com порте, проблема в том, что на форме при открытие отрисовывается много элементов из-за этого все мерцает, количество элементов на форме не возможно сократить, пример формы на картинке ниже [image: Пример формы!]

пример кода при загрузки формы
[image: пример кода]

изменять приложение ради разделения по потокам нет возможности и да картинки, тестовые поля, имена лейбов грузятся из микроконтроллера, только часть из ресурсов проекта.
Может кто-то сталкивался с такой же проблемой и есть универсальное решение, что бы форма загружалась незаметно для пользователя. splash screen или что-то подобное нужно использовать без таймера, т.к. в зависимости от микроконтроллера форма может грузится быстрее ( данных меньше ) либо медленней

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: А почему бы Вам не сделать все эти инициализации в конструкторе формы, после InitializeComponent();? А то если их положить а Load - да, будет мерцать

Comment: @S.H. 1) хотелось бы обойтись малой кровью и не лесть в кучу кода, перенося из load в Initialize, т.к. проект разросся до внушительных масштабов 2) таких форм с мерцающей загрузкой около 100....

Comment: Вставьте код текстом. Нет никакого желания перепечатывать его с картинки, чтобы проверить. Так же можете вставить содержимое Designer.cs файла. А как бороться с мерцанием в Winforms полно гайдов ([например вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25648710/12888024)). И вам бы научиться работать с коллекциями и панелями, а то 12 групп контролов - это очень много, а что если их будет 50. Вы к каждому контролу по имени будете обращаться? ([еще пример с коллекцией кнопок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1296394/373567))

Comment: `foreach (PictureBox pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()) { pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom; pb.Image = Properties.Resources.loadgs; }` еще у `PictureBox` есть свойство `WaitOnLoad`, возможно пригодится. Например перед старотом изначальной прогрузки его можно установить в `true`, а потом вернуть назад в `false`. @S.H. вынос в конструктор не поможет, обработчик `Load` вызывается в любом случае до показа формы.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить [SuspendLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)/ ResumeLayout. | Повключайте двойную буферизацию, где только можно. Правда, у ПикчаБокса она и так включена по умолчанию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я просто похлопаю, это настолько просто, что гениально. Теперь форма на секунду становится черной, а после все элементы уже прогружены, раньше это был просто светофор длящийся примерно 10 секунд. На временную заплатку годится на все бабки

Comment: Не должно быть никаких светофоров. Чего-то вы не договариваете. При правильном обращении с контролами указанной проблемы вообще быть не должно.

Comment: реализацию можно взять отсюда [тык, функция в ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1389260/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-c)