# Как сделать вывод действий для калькулятора C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, калькулятор

Должно получиться как на картинке (вывод действий над итогом счета]

```
    char znak; // Знак
    string a; // Первое число
    string b; // Второе число
    bool pomnish = false; // Для выполнения действия, если не нажали "="
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "4";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "1";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "2";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "3";
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "5";
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "6";
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "7";
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "8";
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "9";
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "0";
    }
    
    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += ",";
    }

    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = null;
        pomnish = false;
    }

    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pomnish) { schitaem(); } // Пригодится в дальнейшем
        znak = '+';
        a = textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Text += "+";
        pomnish = true;
    }

    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pomnish) { schitaem(); }
        znak = '-';
        a = textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Text += "-";
        pomnish = true;
    }

    private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pomnish) { schitaem(); }
        znak = '/';
        a = textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Text += "/";
        pomnish = true;
    }

    private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pomnish) { schitaem(); }
        znak = '*';
        a = textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Text += "*";
        pomnish = true;
    }
    public void schitaem()
    {
        int i = a.Length + 1;
        while (i < textBox1.Text.Length)
        {
            b += textBox1.Text[i]; // Добавляем в переменную b, все цифры после знака
            i++;
        }
        if (znak == '+') { textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(a) + Convert.ToDouble(b)); }
        if (znak == '-') { textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(a) - Convert.ToDouble(b)); }
        if (znak == '*') { textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(a) * Convert.ToDouble(b)); }
        if (znak == '/') { textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(a) / Convert.ToDouble(b)); }
        b = null;
    }

    private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            schitaem();
            pomnish = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: На всякий случай вот [пример интерфейса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1296394/373567), вдруг пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете ввиду значение 1333.66+, то можно завести label в том месте и в коде менять текстовое значение лейбла после нажатия на кнопки.

Допустим вы набрали 1333.66 после нажатия на плюс поле с выводом очищается, а текстовое значение label меняется на то что вы ввели и знак на который нажали, то есть плюс. После нажатия на равно. Вычисляем результат выражения в label, при этом не забыв его очистить.

```
LABEL_NAME.Text += textbox1.Text + " +";
textbox1.Text = '';
```