# Создать список кнопок в WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать список кнопок так что бы индексы шли по порядку возрастания. У меня получается только по убыванию. Если свойство dock поставить в top. Если dock не оставить пустым то кнопки нее растягиваются на всю ширину панели.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = $"Button {i}";
            button.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            panel1.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно идти не от нуля к 10, а от 10 к нулю))))

Comment: Познакомтесь с панелями `FlowLayoutPanel` и `TableLayoutPanel`. https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ItHQA4Z9tRpyqg - проект-пример, где я игрался с `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Вот [еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1296394/373567).

Comment: А вообще такие штуки проще простого можно вытворять в WPF. Winforms - эта штука слегка не про интерфейсы. Точнее возможно всё, но в винформах порой оно делается весьма сложно.

Comment: @aepot в WinForms полно унаследованных тараканов от WinAPI, поверх которого они и работают, и "красивый модный интерфейс" разумеется не про них, это правда, но тут тоже не все так плохо. Другой вопрос, что нормальную документацию по формам сейчас найти довольно сложно, а в целом типовые задачи решаются не сложнее чем в WPF, особенно если не тащить из примеров с MSDN практику использовfния паттерна Active Document, а по максимуму использовать биндинги и вообще минимизировать логику в коде контролов, оставив там только логику отрисовки. Простым задачам простые решения =)

Comment: @rdorn 99,999% погромистов про биндинги в винформах не слышали. Да что уж там, даже `BindingList<T>` встречают с широко открытыми глазами, не говоря уж про `INotifyPropertyChanged` ([пруф](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567)). Ну и рядом шаблон MVP на всех с умилением смотрит.

Comment: @aepot к сожалению, это так, рад бы поспорить, но собственный опыт говорит о том же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способов много, от замены Panel на FlowLayoutPanel или TableLayoutPanel, как уже советовали в комментариях, до создания наследника Panel и переопределения ее поведения при добавлении новых контролов. Каждый из способов, имеет свои плюсы и минусы, это можно обсудить отдельно. Но в вашем случае

> ... Идея состоит в том что данные будут загружаться из файла построчно и добавляться в панель должны в том же порядке ...

для корректного порядка отображения элементов, минимально достаточно каждый новый элемент после добавления в панель перемещать в начало списка контролов. Для этого у коллекции контролов есть метод [SetChildIndex(Control, Int32)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndex);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) Может это и не так красиво и "модно", но достаточно эффективно. Чтобы избежать мерцания при добавлении элемента и изменении его индекса, а оно неизбежно возникнет, т.к. мы меняем порядок элементов и чем элементов больше, тем заметнее мерцание, нужно временно "заморозить" панель, т.е. запретить обновление визуализации дочерних элементов. Для этого используются методы `SuspendLayout()` и `ResumeLayout()`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = $"Button {i}";
        button.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        //чтобы избежать мерцания "замораживаем" панель на время добавления контрола
        panel1.SuspendLayout();
        panel1.Controls.Add(button);
        //перемещаем последний добавленный элемент в начало списка контролов
        panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(button, 0);
        //"размораживаем" панель
        panel1.ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

Таким образом при DockStyle.Top элементы будут отображаться сверху вниз в порядке их добавления на панель, При других вариантах вариантах DockStyle, ну кроме Fill и None, поведение сохранится, порядок контролов будет начинаться со стороны, к которой прижимаются элементы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись без Dock:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button
        {
           Text = "Button " + i,
           Size = new Size(100, 24),
           Location = new Point(4, i * 26 + 4),
        };
        panel1.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Но а если вы все же хотите костыльно исправить это, то можете сделать так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)     
    {
        Button button = new Button
        {
            Text = "Button " + i;
            Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        };
        Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Цикл здесь только для примера заполнения панели кнопками. Идея состоит в том что данные будут загружаться из файла построчно и добавляться в панель должны в том же порядке. Если использовать первый ваш первый способ то при изменении размера Panel компоненты внутри не будут ресайзиться.

Comment: И вам тоже стоит познакомиться с `TableLayoutPanel`.