# Создание динамически n-го количества кнопок C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите разобраться как работать с динамическим созданием обьектов на форме, в моём случае это будут кнопки, есть у меня вот такое решение над которым я работаю:

```
 int x = 5;
 int y = 30;
 int r = 150;//расстояние
 for (int i = 0; i < testList.Count ; i++)
 {
   Button b = new Button();
   b.Location = new Point(( x + i * r), y);
   b.Height = 150;
   b.Width = 150;
   Controls.Add(b);
  }
```

В одну строку я могу вместить 5 кнопок, как мне начать заполнять следующую строку также в 5 кнопок ?
в общей сложности я могу вместить 4 строки в каждой по 5 кнопок.
Какой длины будет список тоже не известно он может быть как 1 так и 10 например, нужно что бы к примеру если длина списка будет 7, 5 кнопок заполнили вехний ряд потом 2 кнопки перешли на другую строку, так же например если будет длина списка 3 тогда все кнопки в один ряд стали, вот тут и столкнулся с проблемой как это реализовать? Может нужно создавать контейнер для этих дел например `Panel` ? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что такое Button? Winforms? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1296394/373567, а вообще `FlowLayoutPanel` и `TableLayoutPanel` к вашим услугам.

Comment: @aepot да Winforms